# Problema ao enviar PHP para MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boa noite. Estou com um grande problema e não consigo resolver. Criei um form para cadastrar e quando clico em enviar, ao invés de enviar, aparece o código do PHP. Eu já instalei o XAMPP e depois o WAMPP, porem não funciona de maneira alguma.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Faça o seu cadastro</title>
    <style>
            td{border:1px solid;}
            body{text-align: center}
            table{al}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="inserir.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="cadastro">
        <h1>CADASTRO</h1>
        <table align="center">
            <tr><td align="left">Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">Rua: <input type="text" name="rua"></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">Cidade: <input type="text" name="cidade"></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">Estado: <input type="text" name="estado"></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">Idade: <input type="number" name="idade" min="0"></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">Peso: <input type="number" name="peso" step="any"></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">Tamanho: <input type="number" name="tamanho" step="any"></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">Nacionalidade: <input type="text" name="nacionalidade"></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Cor do cabelo:<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="corCabelo" value="Preto">Preto
                    <input type="radio" name="corCabelo" value="Loiro">Loiro
                    <input type="radio" name="corCabelo" value="Ruivo">Ruivo
                    <input type="radio" name="corCabelo" value="Outros">Outros
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td align="left">Sexo:<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M">Masculino
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="F">Feminino
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table align="center" style="margin-top: 5px">
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <button type="reset">Apagar</button>
                    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Arquivo **inserir.php**:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
$host  = "localhost";
$user  = "root";
$pass  = "";
$banco = "relacionamentos";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
exit;

$conexao = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysqul_error());
mysql_select_db($banco) or die (mysqul_error());

if($_POST['tipo'] == 'cadastro.html')
{
    $inserir = "insert into cadastro(nome,rua,cidade,estado) values ('$_POST[nome]','$_POST[rua]','$_POST[cidade]',"
        . "'$_POST[estado]','$_POST[idade]','$_POST[peso]','$_POST[tamanho]','$_POST[nacionalidade]',"
        . "'$_POST[corCabelo]','$_POST[sexo]')";

    if (mysql_query($inserir)) {
        echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso!";
    }
}
elseif($_POST['tipo'] == 'buscar')
{
    $peso   = get_peso($_POST['peso']);
    $altura = get_altura($_POST['altura']);
    $cabelo = "cabelo = " . $_POST['corCabelo'];
    $sexo   = "sexo = " . $_POST['sexo'];

    $select = mysql_query("select * from cadastro where $peso and $altura and $cabelo and $sexo");

    $array_busca = array();

    while($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($select))
    {
        $array_busca[] = $ln;
    }

    if(!empty($array_busca))
    {
        foreach($array_busca as $pessoa)
        {
            ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $pessoa['nome']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pessoa['idade']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pessoa['cidade'] . "/" . $pessoa['estado']?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php
        }
    }
}

function get_peso($peso)
{
    switch ($peso)
    {
        case 'menor_40':    return 'peso <= 40';
        case 'entre_40_50': return 'peso >=40 and peso <= 50';
    }
}

function get_altura($altura)
{
    switch ($altura)
    {
        case 'menor_14':    return 'tamanho <= 1.4';
        case 'entre_14_15': return 'tamanho >=1.4 and tamanho <= 1.5';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: são dois arquivos diferentes, certo ?

Comment: Sim sim. É que quando postei, acabou juntando. Um É o cadastro e o outro é Inserir

Comment: Certificou-se se o servidor Apache foi iniciado corretamente? Você está executando esses arquivos no diretório raiz do servidor ou em em qualquer subdiretório deste?

Comment: Aliás, que código PHP seria esse? É o do próprio arquivo ou é algo do tipo `array ( [nome] => ..., [rua] => ... )`?

Comment: Coloquei na pasta raiz do Xampp e do Wampp e não funcionou. E no localHost aparece a pasta.

Comment: Podes me mandar teu e-mail, para eu te enviar o código? Porque teoricamente, o apache está funcionando no Wampp e/ou Xampp

Comment: Quando você envia o POST ele retorna com o código PHP cru do "inserir.php"? Isso?

Comment: Na conexão com o banco de dados, está mesmo a função `mysqul_error`? O correto seria `mysql_error`. Aliás, o correto mesmo era você nem estar usando essas funções `mysql_*`, elas estão obsoletas no PHP 5 e foram removidas do PHP 7; o ideal é utilizar `mysqli_*` ou PDO.

Comment: E no `insert` você apenas especificou as colunas "nome, rua, cidade, estado", mas passou os valores de "nome, rua, cidade, estado, idade, peso, tamanho, nacionalidade, corCabelo, sexo". Por quê isso?

Comment: Porque primeiro iria testar, se funcionasse faria os outros.

Comment: Isso deve estar gerando na sua consulta. Utilize corretamente a função `mysql_error` para verificar, inclusive dentro de um `else` quando executa `mysql_query`.

Comment: rapaz, assim como muitos colegas, estou perplexo com seu código, você deveria remover o print_r($post) assim como mudar muita coisa para por exemplo, pdo ou sqli, tenho uma função de cadastro que utiliza tanto pdo quanto sqli e visando sobre tudo a segurança, caso queira dar umas olhada para ver se gosta, me envia mensagem

Comment: Sou mega iniciante, por isso vários erros =(

Comment: então, caso queira, posso lhe ajudar com muitas melhorias neste script

Comment: Claro que gostaria. Sou iniciante. Estou no 3 período de Ciência da Computação. O professor de BD passou um trabalho, para que apenas apresetassemos um problema e criasse algumas tabelas e inseríssemos.

Comment: Porem, corri atrás para aprender um pouco de HTML, CSS e PHP. E fiz um form para mostrar na pratica.

Meu e-mail:  thunanchiu@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

1-Então troque o `if($_POST['tipo'] == 'cadastro.html')` por `if($_POST['tipo'] == 'cadastro')` porque no value do campo tipo, está só 'cadastro'

2-Quanto a possibilidade de ser problema no servidor web, tente instalar o apache ou vertrigo para fazer testes

3-O seu INSERT está errado... você está dando insert em mais values do que colunas:

-> Somente nome, rua,cidade e estado.... e nos values você informa peso, idade, tamanho, nacionalidade, que não estão no comando do INSERT

```
insert into cadastro(nome,rua,cidade,estado) values ('$_POST[nome]','$_POST[rua]','$_POST[cidade]',"
        . "'$_POST[estado]','$_POST[idade]','$_POST[peso]','$_POST[tamanho]','$_POST[nacionalidade]',"
        . "'$_POST[corCabelo]','$_POST[sexo]')";
```

Comment: Então, essa parte estava comentada, tirei apenas porque não estava pegando daí coloquei para ver se pegava.

Comment: Tirei o .html e ao invés de aparecer o código php, ficou uma página em branco. Porem fui no banco de dados e não adicionou nada.

Comment: mais um erro encontrado, verifique o comando SQL

Comment: Então, iria primeiro testar, depois iria adicionar o resto. No caso, se eu der mais insert do que colunas, não pegará?

Comment: não... você tem que colocar quais colunas e os respectivos valores

Comment: @ThunAnFreitasChiu conseguiu resolver ?

Comment: Consegui sim! Funcionou. Obrigadão mesmo. Agora não sei como faço para retornar.O código buscar não está funcionando.

Comment: A sintaxe SQL do SELECT também está errada... o where tem que ser: Select * from [Tabela] where [nome_da_coluna]=[valor_desejado]